# How can I temporarily fix a cracked bathroom sink?

Tags: repair, sink

Last night I managed to drop something onto my bathroom sink, which now has a large crack in it and is obviously leaking when I turn the tap on. I know I will have to replace the sink, but I cant really afford that at the minute.

Is there something I can maybe put into the sink that will hook over the sides so the water drains into that and down the plughole instead of directly in the sink basin?

Comment: Are you looking for a plastic bag and some duct tape?

Comment: i was kind of hoping someone might have a better suggestion, but its looking that way at the moment!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably fill the crack with epoxy to stop the leak.  It might not look great but it will do the job.

Make sure the area is clean and dry, and that you follow the directions on the packaging.  If there is any chipping make sure to brush away any loose debris so that the epoxy will bond correctly.

As far as what type of epoxy to use, Home Depot carries a [Marine Epoxy](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-100371825/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&keyword=marine+epoxy&storeId=10051) which they describe as:

> Marine Epoxy is a permanent, waterproof adhesive. The 2-part formula is ideal for projects requiring high bonding strength on surfaces exposed to water immersion. The adhesive can be applied and will cure underwater. It can be used on glass, metal, wood and other common materials.

This sounds like it would work well for your application.

Comment: Is there a specific epoxy to look for, or are they all the same. The sink is porcelain

Comment: Added details to answer.

Comment: Looks promising, i'll see if i can get hold of some and give it a try. Thanks a lot